# How has Stack Overflow implemented related tags functionality (Data Structure + Method)?

Tags: discussion, tags, related-tags

I want to know how to implement related tags functionality on a site like Stack Overflow.

I have questions coming with a set of tags (maximum of 5) as input for training the system. I then have to find out related tags given a single/double/triple tag as input.

Example -

1. A user lands on page [First Landing Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solr).
   Observation: User can see list of related tags along with the counts for the tag 1 - solr (in this case)
2. The user clicks on one of the related tags, [Second Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/solr+lucene).
   Observation: The user now sees questions related to both the tags and related tags to both two tags selected together as an entity.

I just need to know an efficient data structure and method to implement the same and am not looking for complete code here. I want to know the implementation part and not the way related tags are defined.

The duplicate suggested question discuss about how those related tags are calculated, not how they are implemented. When we talk about implementation, it means taking about data structures and methods. I know already that it's based on occurrence. Please note that difference.

Let me know if I am unclear in asking my question.

Comment: Hi, that question mentions algorithm of finding out related tags, not implementation. I have mentioned that in question this time.

Comment: For sure this information isn't stored/kept in the database so it might be a responsibility of Tag Engine in which case magic determines its implementation.,,,